# Highcharts "Cannot read property 'toFront' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, object, methods, highcharts

I have a scatter chart and I'm looping through each point and bring it to front if it matches my condition, like this:

```
ptChart.series[0].points.forEach((point) => {
  if (point.options.is_big_town === 1) {
    point.select(true, true);
    point.graphic.toFront();
  }
});
```

But for some point I got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `'toFront'` of `undefined`

I found that some points don't have the `graphic` method but I don't know why, isn't this a default?

### edit

Now I found that if I remove the min/max values from the X and Y axis, for example:

```
    yAxis: {
      title: { text: `${subject === 'pt' ? 'Português' : 'Matemática'} | [Nível de aprendizado]` },
      lineWidth: 1,
      gridZIndex: 0,
      // max: 2,
      // min: -2,
    },
```

Everything works as it should. But now I am even more lost about what is happening.

Comment: Could you prepare a demo in online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: Is the visibility set to `false` by chance? There will be no `graphic` property for invisible points

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I'm trying to make the demo but the things are very kinda huge because the points come from an api and I have a form that filters it, may a live version help?

Comment: @JordanStubblefield, thanks for the guess, but unfortunately not, all the points are always visible on the chart and I'm just toggling them to make a "visual selection" for the user.

Comment: In case it helps, here is a live version @WojciechChmiel (https://dev--wonderful-swanson-f65e38.netlify.com/dados), you can see the error if you change the "destacar por estado" select `id=state` and select "alagoas" option for example.

Comment: Thanks @JordanStubblefield, for pointing out the visibility path... I found it now.

Comment: @EduRuiz Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it after all, special thanks to [Jordan comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868362/highcharts-cannot-read-property-tofront-of-undefined#comment96509539_54868362) that pointed me out on the right direction.

The visibility of the points are not set to false, but the `X` and `Y` axis had a `Max` and `Min` range set, what causes some points to be rendered out of the chart area and generated the error.

Hope it helps someone in the future to not waste 5 hours on this like I did.